# Have coldfusion and asp.net share session variables

Tags: asp.net, session, coldfusion, session-variables, coldfusion-9

I am looking for a way to have ColdFusion and ASP.NET share session variables. I have seen posts in the past saying that you cannot do this directly with out calling some sort of ColdFusion function to return some sort of string representation of the session. I have recently learned about something called ehcache that is a third party session storage tool. That got me wondering is there a third party session tool that will allow ASP.NET and ColdFusion to share a session.

Some details about our systems:

- They are running Windows Server 2008
- We are using IIS
- We are using ColdFusion 9

Comment: This question is very waffley - if you want to know if/how you can share session variables, edit the question to just be about that and you'll likely get more people paying attention. _(If you want help migrating to Railo, asking on the [Railo mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/railo) is probably best place.)_

Comment: @PeterBoughton: I edited the question to be a question and not a description of why one technology is better than the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ColdFusion/Railo and asp.net can use EHCache, but they're very unlikely to share sessions out of the box. Each will have their own session key, which they'll use to put the data in/out. They'll all have their own way of storing the data. I may be wrong, but from memory, ColdFusion uses WDDX, Railo uses something like JSON and I've no idea what the .Net platform uses.

The point is that each hides the complexity of dealing directly with ehcache, but they each do it in their own way. If you want to interoperate, you may need to have each read/write directly to ehcache (or the database). You'll also have to work out a way of sharing a common key between .Net and ColdFusion.

If you're rolling your own version of this, then using JSON proably makes sense as the common format.